# Как назвать тег input переменной

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, html5, ejs

Здрастуйте,у меня есть 1 код:

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <% categories.forEach(element => { %>
        <th><input class="favorite styled" type="button" value="123" /></th>
        <% }); %>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Как мне сделать чтобы value ровнялся element?

Comment: `... value="<%= element.xxx %>"`

Comment: Спасибо,я немного глуплю в ejs,доки прочитал,заучил,но забываю использовать